# Random graphs with a hamiltonian path

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, random-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Suppose we randomly choose a graph with $n$ vertices in the following manner: each edge is included with probability $\frac12$. Thus, each graph has the same probability of being chosen, and there are $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ possible graphs. Denote $H_n$ the event that such a graph contains a Hamiltonian path. Prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(H_n) = 1,$$
that is, as we consider larger and larger graphs, the proportion of graphs that contain a Hamiltonian path approaches $1$.

As a bonus, find an **efficient** algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian path in a graph. The algorithm must also be precise, that is, it must find a Hamiltonian path most of the time. More concretely, we are looking for an algorithm with the following two properties:

- Its average time complexity is polynomial with respect to the number of vertices. (But you should aim for as good as possible.)
- Denote $S_n$ the event that the algorithm succeeds if its input is a random graph with $n$ vertices. Then,
  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(S_n) = 1.$$

So, what have I tried so far? There is a relatively easy way to obtain the lower bound of $0.25$ that holds for all $n$. Denote $X_n[a]$ the event that there exists a Hamiltonian path starting at $a$, in a random graph with $n$ vertices. Clearly, the probability of such an event occuring is the same for all vertices, and we will denote this probability $x$. We can bound $x = P(X_n[a])$ from below as follows:

- If there is at least one edge to some vertex $b$, we can consider Hamiltonian paths that start with vertices $a, b$. The probability that such a Hamiltonian path exists is $P(X_{n-1}[b]) = x_{n-1}$.
- If there is no edge from $a$, there is no Hamiltonian path starting at $a$. The probability of this occuring is $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Thus we obtain the following inequality:
$$x_n \geq (1 - \frac {1}{2^{n-1}}) \cdot x_{n-1}.$$

From this it is easy to prove that $x_n \geq \frac14$ for all $n$. To obtain a better lower bound, we can consider additional cases based on how many edges there are from $a$:

- If there are $0$ adjacent vertices, there is no hope.
- If there is one adjacent vertex, we can reduce to $x_{n-1}$.
- If there are at least $2$ adjacent vertices, denote them $b$ and $c$. The path can go through either $b$ or $c$. Thus, by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the probability that at least one of the paths exists is
  $$P(X_{n-1}[b]) + P(X_{n-1}[c]) - P(X_{n-1}[b] \land X_{n-1}[c]).$$

Thus, if we were to find a good enough upper bound for $P(X_{n-1}[b] \land X_{n-1}[c])$, the problem would be solved. However, such an upper bound eludes me, all I can come up with are lower bounds (which are not helpful).

Alternative forms of the above expression that may help:
$$P(X_{n-1}[b])\ +\ P(X_{n-1}[c] \mid \neg X_{n-1}[b])$$

In this form, we are trying to find a lower bound for the second term, which corresponds to the probability that there exists a Hamiltonian path starting at $c$, given that we know that there is no Hamiltonian path from $b$.

Also, it may be better to consider the case with more vertices adjacent to $a$, such as three. Though with more vertices comes bigger trouble when applying the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: So are you just posting your assignment verbatim?

Comment: This is actually not an assignment, but a problem I came up with (though it seems pretty standard). However I see that here it is required of you to show that you have tried solving the problem before posting, so I will do just that in a minute.

Comment: The [Hamiltonian path problem is NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), so this sounds like a non-starter to me.

Comment: Sure, but in that problem, you are not allowed to make any mistakes. In this problem, you are allowed to make mistakes, provided that as $n \to \infty$ your mistakes go to $0$. The idea is that: "There are too many edges---there must be a Hamiltonian path!"

Comment: @buj: Thanks for making the effort to show your ideas (+1), and welcome to MSE!

Comment: There is only one complete graph on three vertices: $K_3$.  Are there three path graphs on three vertices ($P_3$)—one for each missing edge from $K_3$—or only one, because they're all isomorphic to each other?  This matters for a uniform distribution.

Comment: There are thee path graphs, isomorphism does not matter. I'll update the problem statement. Thanks for pointing that out.

@quasi: Yay, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For context: a result of Pósa says that a random graph with $C n \log n$ edges already contains a Hamiltonian path with probability tending to $1$, and here we have a uniformly random graph (with $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges on average). So we can be fairly wasteful.

As far as an algorithm goes, we can take the algorithm used to prove [Dirac's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem). The hypotheses of that theorem don't hold here, but the algorithm will still work with high probability. The strategy is this:

1. Pick a path greedily: start at a vertex $v_1$, pick a vertex $v_2$ it is adjacent to, then pick a vertex $v_3$ adjacent to $v_2$, and so on. Repeat until you get stuck.
2. Turn the path into a cycle: if it has endpoints $v_1$ and $v_\ell$, find adjacent vertices $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ on the path such that $v_{i+1}$ is adjacent to $v_1$ and $v_i$ is adjacent to $v_\ell$. Then the cycle is $v_1, \dots, v_i, v_\ell, \dots, v_{i+1}, v_1$.
3. Turn the cycle into a longer path: if $v_{\ell+1}$ is a vertex not on the cycle, find a vertex $v$ on the cycle adjacent to $v_{\ell+1}$, and take the path starting next to $v$, going around the cycle, and then going to $v_{\ell+1}$.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the path contains all the vertices.

All of these steps are quite likely to work individually. The problem is that to analyze how likely they are to work as a whole, we'd have to check edges of the graph multiple times, which doesn't preserve independence.

So instead, we will write our uniformly random graph $G$ as the union of graphs $G_0, G_1, \dots, G_{10 \log n}$, where $G_0$ contains each edge independently with probability $\frac14$, and $G_1, \dots, G_{10 \log n}$ contain each edge independently with probability $p$, chosen so that $\frac34(1-p)^{10 \log n} = \frac12$. Then the union will contain each edge with probability $\frac12$, so it will be the uniformly random graph. If we solve for $p$, we get $p = O(\frac{1}{\log n})$, but all we'll really need is for $p$ to be asymptotically bigger than $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

Then I claim that:

1. A greedy path chosen in $G_0$ will reach length $n - 5\log n$ with very high probability.
2. Doing step 2 of the algorithm in any of the $G_1, \dots, G_{10 \log n}$ will work with very high probability.
3. Doing step 3 of the algorithm in any of the $G_1, \dots, G_{10 \log n}$ will work with very high probability.

Then we can just look at graphs $G_0, G_1, \dots$ sequentially as we go through the algorithm. This preserves independence, and if the edges we need will be in the graph $G_i$ we're looking at, they will be in the union $G$.

For the first claim: the probability that a greedy path will get stuck while there's still $5 \log n$ vertices to pick from is $(\frac34)^{5\log n} = n^{-5\log \frac43}$, so the probability is at most $n^{1 - 5\log \frac43} \approx n^{-0.43}$ that it ever gets stuck.

For the second claim: we have at least $\frac n2$ options for vertices $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$, and each one works with probability $p^2$. The probability that none of them work is $(1-p^2)^{n/2} \le e^{-p^2n/2}$, which approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$. (This is where we want $p \gg \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, so that the exponent goes to $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. We actually want a bit better than that, because we want all $O(\log n)$ of these steps to work, so the probability should go to $0$ faster than $\frac{1}{\log n}$. But our $p$ is actually quite a bit larger than $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, so we have that wiggle room.)

For the third claim: we have at least $\frac n2$ options for the vertex $v$, and each works with probability $p$. The probability that none of them work is $(1-p)^{n/2} \le e^{-pn/2}$, which approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$.